# How can I "ellipsify" lengthy text in a Rails application?

Tags: string, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to configure an arbitrary maximum display length for certain text fields in my Rails 3.2.13 application.

I would like this helper to create an ellipsis link at the end of the abbreviated string that would then display the full text string in a little popup window. Is there a gem that already does this, or do I need to roll my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a gem, use `truncate`:

```
truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", :length => 17)
# => "Once upon a ti..."
```

[Docs on apidock.com](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/truncate)